# Cannot make work Net5 with Ubuntu 20.04 (OpenSSL connection problem)

Tags: asp.net-core, tls1.2, dotnet-httpclient, ubuntu-20.04, .net-5

I have migrated an application from NetCore 3.1 and Ubuntu 18.04 to Net5 and Ubuntu 20.04.

The application has begun failing when a HttpWebRequest object calls the GetResponse method.

I have found a notice from Microsoft warning about major changes in the behaviour, see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux

And a very interesting post (generic for Linux, not related with Net5) in
https://medium.com/siberians-pro/how-to-use-tlsv1-on-ubuntu-20-04-133c2898ad7

But both are not working for me.

What I have tried until now:

1. I have created a specific local openssl.cnf file, with this content

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init
    
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect
    
[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect
    
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

2. I have exported the variable `OPENSSL_CONF` pointing this file

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=/var/www/spider/openssl.cnf
```

3. I launch my code normally

```
dotnet Spider.dll
```

4. And I get the exception

```
fail: Spider.Program[0]
      [19/12/2020 08:50:52.724]: Error getting response from https://www.boe.es/diario_boe/xml.php?id=BOE-S-20201216
      System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
       ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
       ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(Boolean isAsync, Boolean isApm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandlerStage.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest(Boolean async)
         at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
         at Common.Services.WebContent.GetXmlContent() in xxxxxxxxx/ContentService.cs:line 671
```

NOTICE: I have also tried

1. Change the global `openssl.cnf` in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`
2. Test the same URL with `curl -vvv`. It works WITH NO change in openssl.cnf, and shows a correct TLSv1.2 negotiation (in my URL, to AES128-SHA256)
3. Test the same URL with `openssl s_client -connect host:port`. Again, run with no problems.

UPDATE: I have created a simple test code. This code runs without problems in Net5 in Mac, and in a docker container but fails with the previous error in Ubuntu 20.04

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BugSSL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Curl("https://www.boe.es/diario_boe/xml.php?id=BOE-S-20201216");
        }

        static void Curl(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request;
            HttpWebResponse response;

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("START-------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine($"Getting URL ${url}");
                request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
                request.Method = "GET";
                
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "SSLBugTest/0.0.0");
                using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Response status: {response.StatusCode} {response.StatusDescription}");
                    Console.WriteLine("Response headers");
                    foreach(string header in response.Headers)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"    {header}: {response.GetResponseHeader(header)}");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"Content-Type: {response.ContentType}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Content-Length: {response.ContentLength}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("END---------------------------------------------------");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TextWriter stderr = Console.Error;
                stderr.WriteLine($"Error processing {url}. Error: {e.Message}");
                stderr.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                while(e.InnerException!=null)
                {
                    e = e.InnerException;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Inner exception: {e.Message}");
                    stderr.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE1: I have found this issue in github, but it has been closed without diagnostic or solution
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44191

UPDATE2: I suspected the problem was that Net5 was not using the configured CipherStrings, and I created a test to use all internally configured. THIS DID NOT WORK, but, maybe, the code can help for further diagnose

```
        static async Task Curl2(string url)
        {
            List<TlsCipherSuite> cipherSuites;
            SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions;
            SocketsHttpHandler socketHttpHandler;
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            Console.WriteLine("START-------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Using HttpClient and custom socket (custom SslOptions)");

            cipherSuites = new List<TlsCipherSuite>();
            foreach (TlsCipherSuite cipherSuite in (TlsCipherSuite[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(TlsCipherSuite)))
            {
                cipherSuites.Add(cipherSuite);
            }

            sslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions();
            //sslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
            //{
            //    CipherSuitesPolicy = new CipherSuitesPolicy(cipherSuites)
            //};
            try
            {
                sslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions();
                socketHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
                {
                    SslOptions = sslOptions
                };
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(socketHttpHandler, true);
                using (response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Response status: {response.StatusCode}");
                    Console.WriteLine("Response headers");
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in response.Headers)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"    {header.Key}: ");
                        foreach (string value in header.Value)
                        {
                            Console.Write($"{value} ");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TextWriter stderr = Console.Error;
                stderr.WriteLine($"Error processing {url}. Error: {e.Message}");
                stderr.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                while (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    e = e.InnerException;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Inner exception: {e.Message}");
                    stderr.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("END---------------------------------------------------");


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug in
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46271
is solved.

The problem was in the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`.
This openssl.cnf works (check `CipherString` and `CipherSuites` at the end of the file)

```
#
# OpenSSL example configuration file.
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
#

# Note that you can include other files from the main configuration
# file using the .include directive.
#.include filename

# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME            = .

openssl_conf = openssl_init


# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
#oid_file       = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section     = new_oids

# To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
# "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
# X.509v3 extensions to use:
# extensions        =
# (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
# X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)

[ new_oids ]

# We can add new OIDs in here for use by 'ca', 'req' and 'ts'.
# Add a simple OID like this:
# testoid1=1.2.3.4
# Or use config file substitution like this:
# testoid2=${testoid1}.5.6

# Policies used by the TSA examples.
tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir     = ./demoCA      # Where everything is kept
certs       = $dir/certs        # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      # Where the issued crl are kept
database    = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.
#unique_subject = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                    # several certs with same subject.
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts     # default place for new certs.

certificate = $dir/cacert.pem   # The CA certificate
serial      = $dir/serial       # The current serial number
crlnumber   = $dir/crlnumber    # the current crl number
                    # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
crl     = $dir/crl.pem      # The current CRL
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key

x509_extensions = usr_cert      # The extensions to add to the cert

# Comment out the following two lines for the "traditional"
# (and highly broken) format.
name_opt    = ca_default        # Subject Name options
cert_opt    = ca_default        # Certificate field options

# Extension copying option: use with caution.
# copy_extensions = copy

# Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
# so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
# crlnumber must also be commented out to leave a V1 CRL.
# crl_extensions    = crl_ext

default_days    = 365           # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = default       # use public key default MD
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy      = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

# For the 'anything' policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extensions to add to the self signed cert

# Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
# input_password = secret
# output_password = secret

# This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options.
# default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
# pkix   : PrintableString, BMPString (PKIX recommendation before 2004)
# utf8only: only UTF8Strings (PKIX recommendation after 2004).
# nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
# MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
# WARNING: ancient versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings.
string_mask = utf8only

# req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = AU
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)

0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName     = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default = World Wide Web Pty Ltd

organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
#organizationalUnitName_default =

commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max          = 64

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_max        = 64

# SET-ex3           = SET extension number 3

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20

unstructuredName        = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This is required for TSA certificates.
# extendedKeyUsage = critical,timeStamping

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA


# PKIX recommendation.

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer

basicConstraints = critical,CA:true

# Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
# left out by default.
# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign

# Some might want this also
# nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA

# Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# Copy issuer details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
# obj=DER:02:03
# Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
# You can even override a supported extension:
# basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF

[ crl_ext ]

# CRL extensions.
# Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.

# issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ proxy_cert_ext ]
# These extensions should be added when creating a proxy certificate

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This really needs to be in place for it to be a proxy certificate.
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo

####################################################################
[ tsa ]

default_tsa = tsa_config1   # the default TSA section

[ tsa_config1 ]

# These are used by the TSA reply generation only.
dir     = ./demoCA      # TSA root directory
serial      = $dir/tsaserial    # The current serial number (mandatory)
crypto_device   = builtin       # OpenSSL engine to use for signing
signer_cert = $dir/tsacert.pem  # The TSA signing certificate
                    # (optional)
certs       = $dir/cacert.pem   # Certificate chain to include in reply
                    # (optional)
signer_key  = $dir/private/tsakey.pem # The TSA private key (optional)
signer_digest  = sha256         # Signing digest to use. (Optional)
default_policy  = tsa_policy1       # Policy if request did not specify it
                    # (optional)
other_policies  = tsa_policy2, tsa_policy3  # acceptable policies (optional)
digests     = sha1, sha256, sha384, sha512  # Acceptable message digests (mandatory)
accuracy    = secs:1, millisecs:500, microsecs:100  # (optional)
clock_precision_digits  = 0 # number of digits after dot. (optional)
ordering        = yes   # Is ordering defined for timestamps?
                # (optional, default: no)
tsa_name        = yes   # Must the TSA name be included in the reply?
                # (optional, default: no)
ess_cert_id_chain   = no    # Must the ESS cert id chain be included?
                # (optional, default: no)
ess_cert_id_alg     = sha1  # algorithm to compute certificate
                # identifier (optional, default: sha1)

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_config

[ssl_config]
system_default = tls_defaults

[tls_defaults]
CipherString = @SECLEVEL=2:kEECDH:kRSA:kEDH:kPSK:kDHEPSK:kECDHEPSK:-aDSS:-3DES:!DES:!RC4:!RC2:!IDEA:-SEED:!eNULL:!aNULL:!MD5:-SHA384:-CAMELLIA:-ARIA:-AESCCM8
Ciphersuites = TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my code in .NET 5 that works both in Windows and Linux machine (via docker):

My solution is based off from the github discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22507

With this code, there is no need to change config settings on your Linux machine.

```
// Windows OS throws PlatformNotSupportedException for explicit list of TlsCipherSuite
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    services.AddHttpClient("WebsiteCheck"), configureClient =>
    {
        configureClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    });
}
else
{
    services.AddHttpClient("WebsiteCheck"), configureClient =>
    {
        configureClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var allowedCipherSuites = Enum.GetValues<TlsCipherSuite>();

        return new SocketsHttpHandler()
        {
            SslOptions = new()
            {
                CipherSuitesPolicy = new CipherSuitesPolicy(allowedCipherSuites)
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET 5 tries to use SSLv3, which is (and should be) disabled. (in Debian 10 among others)

The solution is to add this line before you make any https calls:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

(Don't forget to remove/replace `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;` in the original post)

No need to change or fiddle with `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`, `CipherString`, etc.

Comment: you solution not work.